# Unsure how to write Flutter test to test private method (test for Flutter's repository)

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I fixed some code in the flutter repository and submitted a pull request ([here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/43735)) but I need to write tests for it to be approved. I've looked at other unit tests for Flutter but none help me for my specific case because mine is different than other PRs I think (please look at my PR so you understand the context). How do I write a Flutter test my new code?

**What I need to check for**

I need to make sure that the value passed into `_buildHeadingCell`'s `onSort` parameter is null if no value is passed to a `DataColumn`'s `onSort` parameter. I'm not allowed to modify `flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/data_table.dart` for testing, only `flutter/packages/flutter/test/material/data_table_test.dart`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, private methods cannot be unit tested. What I would do in my projects is I would make the methods I want to test public, but annotate them with [@visibleForTesting](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/meta/visibleForTesting-constant.html). Basically this annotation makes a method private to the whole project except for the file it its defined in and the `test` directory.

It looks like you cannot change the source code, I do not know if you can ask for this kind of changes, so I guess you can write a widget test for it.

Comment: "I guess you can write a widget test for it" doesn't help me. I've looked at widget tests but none are similar to my case. How would I write one for this case? It doesn't seem like a widget test would be applicable for my scenario.